# JSON loop android is not working

Tags: android, json, loops

I am trying to get data from a MySQL(Xampp) database with Android using a PHP file. I got the required data in a String variable, but it seems my method does not enter the for-loop. Below is my code.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
protected void onPostExecute(String result){         
    //parse json data    
    try {
        System.out.println("in jsn try");
        String s = "";
        System.out.println("after jsn string s");
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        System.out.println("after creating json array "+result);// it executes fine and prints all records
        System.out.println("jarray lenght is "+jArray.length());// it execute fine and prints the length 3 which is fine
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {      // problem here 
            System.out.print("in jsn loop");
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            System.out.print("json object");
            s = s +"Name : "+json.getString("Name")+" "+json.getString("Email");  
        }
        System.out.print("Success in json" +s);
        //  resultView.setText(s);   
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data "+e.toString()); 
    }    
}
```

the response variable prints 3 records

```
[
    {
        "PId":"1111",
        "Name":"Rukhsar",
        "Email":"rukhsar_arshad93@yahoo.com",
        "Address":"Rawalpindi"
    },
    {
        "PId":"2222",
        "Name":"Sidra",
        "Email":"sidra_arshad@yahoo.com",
        "Address":"Rawalpindi"
    }, 
    {
        "PId":"3333",
        "Name":"Sehrish ",
        "Email":"sehrishali686@yahoo.com",
        "Address":"Islamabad"
    }
]
```

Comment: Please share json response from php web-service

Comment: have you debug your code any time ?

Comment: Use `optString` instead of `getString` and post Json response as well here. Access `PId` and `Address` as well from Json.

Comment: So what is `jArray.length()` ?

Comment: A) what is the `//problem here`? Exception? Does you computer blow up? B) what happens when you do `System.out.println(jArray.toString(4));` C) What library/jar are you using?

Comment: jArray.lenght(); prints 3

Comment: i just edit the code by accessing PId and Address as well but the control is not entering inside loop and not even printing any statement

Comment: @SadiaAsghar Just print this line in loop  `System.out.print("in jsn loop");` and comment other line. And check if it is print or not.

Comment: @SadiaAsghar you haven't pasted the logcat/stack trace, you haven't even explained what you mean by **problem here**. How do you expect people to help you here?

Comment: i comment the the code inside loop except System.out.println("in jsn loop"); but the result is same its not printing this line

Comment: @Sufian there is no error in logcat the problem is that the control is not entering in loop and not executing any statement even simple print statement is not printing i don't know why ...

Comment: @SadiaAsghar post your logcat/stack trace anyway

Comment: Not that you do **not** have `System.out.println("in json loop")` in your code. You have `System.out.print("in json loop")`. But you're in Android, use `Log.w("TAG", "myerror")` instead of syso's. Or run it in the debugger with a breakpoint in the for-loop. You'll see, it does enter the loop.

Comment: @stealthjong You'r right. But it doesn't matter!!!

Comment: yes you are right @stealthjong i just change the print to println and now it prints the statement 3 times but now the problem is in this statment s = s +"Name : "+json.optString("PId")+" "+json.optString("Name")+" "+json.optString("Email")+" "+json.optString("Address");  }

Comment: @SadiaAsghar actually at this pace this question will be closed. I advise you to please update your question with logcat. It's not too difficult.

Comment: Thank you all the problem is solved by using println instead of print :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
protected void onPostExecute(String result){         
    //parse json data    
    try {
        System.out.println("in jsn try");
        String s = "";
        System.out.println("after jsn string s");
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        System.out.println("after creating json array "+result);// it executes fine and prints all records
        System.out.println("jarray lenght is "+jArray.length());// it execute fine and prints the length 3 which is fine
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {      // problem here 
            System.out.print("in jsn loop");
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            System.out.print("json object");
            s = s +"Name : "+json.getString("Name")+" "+json.getString("Email");  
        }
        System.out.print("Success in json" +s);
        //  resultView.setText(s);   
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data "+e.toString()); 
    }    
}
```

I see a few issues with this code. First off, you use `System.out.print` instead of `System.out.println`. Even better, because you're working with Android, is the use of `Log.w(String, String)`. Also

```
s = s +"Name : "+json.getString("Name")+" "+json.getString("Email");
```

You should append a newline:

```
String line = "Name : "+json.getString("Name")+" "+json.getString("Email");
s += line + "\n"; //so it starts on a newline
Log.d("json", line); //while you're at it, Log that line!
```

**Addition**:

You should make use of the debugger! Add a breakpoint in your for loop, and run in debug mode! Standard feature in Eclipse, works with Android too.

**Edit**

So my take on your code would be:

```
private static final String NAME = "Name";
private static final String EMAIL = "Email";

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {       
    try {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject user = array.getJSONObject(i);
            resultView.append("Name : " + user.getString(NAME) + " - " + user.getString(EMAIL) + "\n");
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException jse) {
        Log.wtf("error", "cant parse json"); //yeah, Log.wtf actually exists :)
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you the problem is solved by using println instead of print :)

Comment: @SadiaAsghar you should mark this answer as correct since stealthjong pointed out the problem your code had.

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your problem

```
public class User {
    private String Pid;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String address;

    //implement getter setters
    //implement to string method
}

public void parseJSON(String result) {          
    try {   
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        List<User> usersList = new ArrayList<User>();
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {      // problem here 
            User user = new User();
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            user.setPid(json.getString("PId"));
            user.setName(json.getString("Name"));
            user.setEmail(json.getString("Email"));
            user.setAddress(json.getString("Address"));

            Log.i("User data is : ",User.toString);
            usersList.add(user);
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data "+e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you the problem is solved by using println instead of print :)